# How to Center and Color a Word in a GridDataView Column?

Tags: c#, datagridview, colors, center

I'm wondering how to center and color a word in a GridDataView Column?

```
               trash trash FIRST trash trash trash trash trash tras...
   trash trash trash trash SECOND trash trash trash trash
...trash trash trash trash THIRD trash trash trash tra
```

In the above example, "FIRST", "SECOND", "THIRD" are supposed be colored and centered.

If the width of the Column is not wide enough, left end or right end should display "..." as in the example.

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks. I appreciate your time.

Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a workaround, and it works pretty close to what I want, and my client also accept it:
[C# DataGridView: Long Text Truncated with "..." on the Left Side When the Column is Right-Aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902341/c-datagridview-long-text-truncated-with-on-the-left-side-when-the-column)