# Long strings inside DataGridViewTextBoxColumn – show their end, not start

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, datagridview, alignment

How to adjust or inherit **DataGridViewTextBoxColumn** so end of string is visible? Current behavior is that left part of string is visible even with right alignment (if the string is too long).

Have a sample file path:

```
D:\Data\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsApplication1\filename.txt
```

In **DataGridViewTextBoxColumn** it looks like

```
+----------------------------------+
|DataGridViewTextBoxColumn1        |
+----------------------------------+
|D:\Data\Visual Studio 2015\Project|   <-- left-aligned long value - OK
|D:\Data\Visual Studio 2015\Project|   <-- right-aligned long value - CURRENT BEHAVIOR
|s\WindowsApplication1\filename.txt|   <-- I NEED RIGHT ALIGNMENT LIKE THIS
+----------------------------------+
```

[→ View the above as graphics.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EG1P3.png)

*(C# or VB – whatever you prefer.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `DataGridViewLeftCropTextBoxColumn` class from this thread:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29516395/904156

Comment: Nice... what to say... closing my own question as a duplicate :)