# Custom truncation for WinForms datagrid cells?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I have a DataGrid that contains a column for key values (binary).  The first 60ish digits are the same, but it's unique past that.  What I'd like to do is to have the truncation in the middle:

```
0xAA00BB00CC...8A3B7F10CE829 // good
```

instead of at the end:

```
0xAA00BB00CC00DD00EE00FF0... // bad
```

That's easy enough to do manually... except when the window containing the data grid gets resized, the data will stay in its manually-truncated form.  Ideally, when the cell is resized, it would reveal more of the unique portion of the binary at the end.  However, by truncating manually, I no longer have that

The obvious way to do this is to cache all of the full values and subscribe to the `Resized` event, but that seems like an awful lot of overhead when a custom `TruncateString()` delegate might do.

What's the best solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use [code from similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29516395/2392157) (ellipses on the left) to create your own column type.
2. The only thing you have to change (except of type name) is which part of the string you draw into the cell.  Now it is placing ellipses on the left. Place them in the middle instead – where you need. It should be easy, but if you need help, let me know.

I tested the solution (I needed it as it is) – it worked great.