# System.Windows.Forms DataGridView show trailing text instead of leading text PowerShell

Tags: .net, forms, powershell

I'm trying to get a DataGridView cell to show the last # of characters of its value instead of showing the first # of characters.

So the goal is to make the cells display as

`[...Store\LANE3\UAT]`

Instead of :

`[DataStore\LANE3...]`

I'm using powershell to create the Form objects. I think I need to somehow hook the DrawText or TextRender functions.. but I'm not sure how and my Google Fu has failed me.

(I could just make the cell width wider but I'd like to keep everything uniform width if possible)

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the string, then substring to get the number of characters you want then replace. Say, something like this...

```
($FormElementString = '[DataStore\LANE3\LANE3\UAT]')
($ReplaceString     = $FormElementString.Substring(1,4))
($FormElementString -replace "\$ReplaceString", "...")
# Results
<#
[DataStore\LANE3\LANE3\UAT]
Data
[...Store\LANE3\LANE3\UAT]
#>
```

***Update as per your comment.***

> I was hoping to keep the same value in the datagridview cell but just
> display it differently in the system.windows.forms datagridview
> object.

If you really are wanting to change the cell-specific view vs the default rendering/truncation, there is a lot more work involved.

See this SO Q&A, note it's all a C#.

[C# DataGridView: Long Text Truncated with "..." on the Left Side When the Column is Right-Aligned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902341/c-sharp-datagridview-long-text-truncated-with-on-the-left-side-when-the-c/29516395#29516395)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was hoping to keep the same value in the datagridview cell but just display it differently in the system.windows.forms datagridview object. I sort of have a work around now. I put the actual value in an array, and set the datagridview cell to the array key of the array object that has the full text value. Not exactly how I wanted to do it.. so I'll see if anyone can help me figure out how to change the way the datagridview cell displays (or draws) its text content.

Comment: No worries, The value would still of course be available in the variable (though displayed differently in the control). So, you could still get at that string, but calling from the variable vs the control.

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex for this:

```
$str = '[DataStore\LANE3\LANE3\UAT]' -replace '^(.).*(.{22})$', '$1...$2'
$str
```

Result:

```
[...Store\LANE3\LANE3\UAT]
```

Regex details:

```
^             Assert position at the beginning of the string
(             Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   .          Match any single character
)
.             Match any single character
   *          Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(             Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   .          Match any single character
      {22}    Exactly 22 times
)
$             Assert position at the end of the string, or before the line break at the end of the string, if any (line feed)
```

Comment: Not exactly what I need but that is very neat. I'm hoping to keep the datagridview cell content the same value but just display it differently (have it draw its cell text differently) to display the trailing content instead of the leading # of characters. I've seen people describe how to do it in C# with system.windows.forms datagridview objects but I'm not sure how to translate that to powershell functions.